# in map() Images Files rerender and redownload everytime useState changes. Is there anything we can do? Like UseMemo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

This is a Chat app with channels like Slack App. Now, I have a map() function with filtering. The array has all the channels data. When I change the channel, it filters out it's chat (messages and Images). But the problem is, when it filters out or when the State changes, it rerenders and redownloads the images. Can we use useMemo() Hook anyhow?

[Please check this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asHAK.gif)

Here is a short piece of Code.

```
{ChatsState.filter((o: any) => {
   return o.Channel.Name === SelectedChannel.Name;
   }).map((Chat: any, index: any, { length }) => (
     <img
      src={
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_GRAPHQL +
        Chat.Username.Image.url
      }
      alt=""
      height={35}
      width={35}
      style={{ borderRadius: "5px" }}/>
))}
```

I have seen Many examples of useMemo() but how to do it when filtering stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would consider is to add key property, so that React is aware that those are unique entries and library optimization mechanics can kick in.

Second of all would be to have some smart mechanism of caching of those images. If for some reason browser is not doing it, you can still enforce it and simply memoize which channels were already visited thus remember those images.

Memoizing of image file in browser is simple - you need to have an image object instantiated so that browser will fetch that image, as long as you dont remove that element, it will be available instantly as long as you refer using the same url. Still, it should work out of the box in context of any modern browser as images are one of the first things to be cached.

Two possible solutions on actually loading images into the browser without actually showing it:

no 1.

```
const img = new Image();
img.src = url;
```

no 2.

```
<link rel="preload" href="{url}" as="image">
```

No 2. is a bit of a long shot, but worth a try.

Comment: Thank you Marcus for that knowledge. I just needed that hint. Thank you again 